# Testing inside the Angular-UI Bootstrap dialog promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular-UI Bootstrap dialogs and loving them, but I seem to be having trouble figuring out how to test what comes back from them when they are closed (or anything else inside the promise for that matter.) Can somebody point me to an example of how this is tested? I suspect that I am just not mocking it correctly. Here's what I have for tests:

```
spyOn(scope.orderDetailsModal, 'open').andReturn({then:function(){return "fulfill";}});
scope.orderDetailsModal.isOpen = function(){return true;};
scope.orderDetails();
expect(scope.orderDetailsModal.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

scope.orderDetailsModal.isOpen = function(){return false;};
scope.orderDetails();
scope.$digest();
expect(scope.orderDetailsModal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(scope.testresult).toEqual("fulfill");
```

Of course, the test for scope.testresult fails. Needless to say, I'm feeling a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an actual promise as the return value of `open`:

```
it('sets result to foobar', function() {
  // Arrange
  var deferred;
  dialogMock.dialog.andCallFake(function () { return dialogMock; });
  dialogMock.open.andCallFake(function () { deferred = $q.defer(); return deferred.promise; });

  // Act
  $scope.openDialog();
  deferred.resolve('foobar');
  $scope.$digest();

  // Assert
  expect($scope.result).toBe('foobar');
});
```

Check out the full code in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kKs9xBh4yo1dwrEPK7o9?p=preview) script.

Comment: Ok, cool. I have no idea why using an actual promise did not occur to me. Thanks!